# I accidentally change a variable with a conditional sentence ( if )?

Tags: c, function, matrix, functional-programming

Information about the code down below: the function initialise players code is:

```
void initialise_players (tvector_players *vj){
int i;  
  for (i=0; i< (vj->nplayers); i++){
      vj->vjug [i].letter = 'A'+i;
      vj->vjug [i].num_regiones = 0;

  }
}
```

past the previous function call, inside the second for (for (j=0; j < (mapa->num_cols+1);  j++)) i am giving a character to "map->p[i+1].m[j+1].player_id".
Then i print it and everything's ok at the moment. But then i use a conditional sentence which should not influence in any way the last variable and i print it again but this time the value of the variable "map->p[i+1].m[j+1].player_id" changes to 'A' for no reason. It would be understandable if the first character given was the 'A' but most of the times its not. Why?

```
    initialise_players (vj);
    for (i=0; i < (map->rows+1); i++){
        for (j=0; j < (mapa->num_cols+1);  j++){
            map->p[i+1].m[j+1].player_id = 'A'+rand()%vj->nplayers;

            printf ("\n%c\n", map->p[i+1].m[j+1].jugador_id);

            if (map->p[i+1].m[j+1].jugador_id = 'A'){

                 printf ("\n%c\n", map->p[i+1].m[j+1].jugador_id);

                 vj->vjug[0].num_regiones += 1;
             }
        }
    }
show_matrix (map, vj);
```

Comment: `=` is used for assignment. use `==` for equality check

Comment: sorry for being retarded, i just spent the last 4 hours trying to find a solution.ty so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two operators in play here, `=` (assignment operator) and `==` (equal to (conditional) operator). The assignment operator(`=`) "assigns" the value on the right to the variable on the left. The result value of an assignment statement (say `a=b`) is `b`, ie the value being assigned.

The conditional operator on the other hand checks wether the values on either side are equal or not. If yes, the resultant value of the expression is `1` otherwise it is `0`.

---

Now in `C` any non zero value is treated as `true` and zero is treated as `false`. Thus the value of the expression `map->p[i+1].m[j+1].jugador_id = 'A'`is the value of `A`(in ASCII 65) which is non zero and hence true. That's why the if block is executed. But at the same time to check for the "trueness" of the condition the condition itself has to executed. The condition executes, and value of the variable is set to `A`

Answer (score 3):

`map->p[i+1].m[j+1].jugador_id = 'A'` is an *expression* of type `int`<sup>1</sup> equal to whatever `'A'` is equal to.

On every possible *encoding*<sup>2</sup>, `'A'` is non-zero, so your `if` block will always run.

Solution: replace `=` with `==`.

Some folk write `'A' == map->p[i+1].m[j+1].jugador_id` to induce compile time failures if they slip an `==`.

---

<sup>1</sup>I am not wrong. `'A'` is an `int` literal in C, and a `char` literal in C++.

<sup>2</sup>The C standard insists that `'A'` **cannot** be 0.

Comment: Agreed on the tips to use constant 'A' in the left side of `==`

Answer (score 1):

```
map->p[i+1].m[j+1].jugador_id = 'A'
```

is always going to be true in the if condition, because the assignment operator =
is used instead of the equivalency operator ==. This means that everytime this if statement is reached, that instead of comparing the variable with 'A', what it is actually doing is setting the value to 'A'. Since the ASCII value of 'A' is not zero, the if statement will always evaluate to true.

The simple fix is to change the statement to have the equivalency operator == instead, so that it compares the value to 'A', and then runs the if block if it is true.